# Using RedHat's OpenJDK in Amazon Linux, and Windows?

Tags: java

RedHat provides a timeline for support for Java versions [here](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1299013). If I want to receive those updates, can I, on platforms other than RHEL? Specifically, Amazon Linux servers and Windows or Mac Desktops (for development)?

I'm wondering if RedHat is making fixes/improvements, do those get pushed upstream to Oracle's [OpenJDK](https://openjdk.java.net/)? If not, it seems I need to make sure I get the JDK from RedHat, for their ongoing support to make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer. RedHat pushes its changes upstream, which then flow back down to other distros.

https://twitter.com/neugens/status/1034839076044775426